# How to define a Structuremap named instance in Code

Tags: .net, structuremap

I want to create a Structuremap named instance in code, without config file

I want to be able to create the instance like this:

```
var namedInjector = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IInjectable>("Other");
```

I cant define such a type in code. I have found [this](http://www.codebucket.org/archive/2008/08/10/three-ways-to-register-dependencies-with-structuremap-2.4.9.aspx) sample
but it uses the old syntax of a previous version and defines the named instance as:

```
.ForRequestedType<MementoType>()
.AddConcreteType<ConcreteType>(instanceName)
```

In the latest structuremap version there is no     .AddConcreteType(instanceName) method which takes a instance name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you need something like:

```
class MyRegistry : Registry {
    public MyRegistry() {
        this.ForRequestedType<IFoo>()
            .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<Bar>()
            .AddInstances( x => {
                x.OfConcreteType<Blap>().WithName("abc");
            });
    }
}
...
ObjectFactory.Configure(x=>x.AddRegistry<MyRegistry>());
IFoo test1 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFoo>(); // Bar
IFoo test2 = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFoo>("abc"); // Blap
...
interface IFoo {}
public class Bar : IFoo {}
public class Blap : IFoo {}
```

Comment: Any idea on the new syntax for StructureMap on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the words of new syntax:

```
            For<IEncryptionService>()
                .AddInstances(x => { x.OfConcreteType<AdvancedEncryptionService>().Named("Advanced"); })
                .Use<EncryptionService>();
```