# StructureMap with multiple LinqToSql DataContexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, structuremap, unit-of-work

I'm on a ASP.NET MVC project and I'm using a generic repository on Data Layer.

This app uses 3 differents DataContexts to manage 3 differents databases.

It works great so far.

Now, I'm trying to archieve Unit Of Work and it's working but only if a inject a specific DataContext instance. Is there a way to inject a generic DataContext class and StructureMap instantiates the right DataContext for me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Named Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671418/how-to-define-a-structuremap-named-instance-in-code) are going to be your best bet. Register each context with a name representing the database, then you can resolve the correct DataContext with just a name.